# Auto-mount USB drives read-only

Tags: linux, mount, usb-storage, automount

I'm currently setting up a laptop for my grandparents to use. They have never used a computer before, so I'm trying to make this as fool-proof as possible. The system will be setup with Ubuntu 10.10.

In order to save them the hassle of having to unmount USB drives before disconnecting them, I would like to have all USB drives auto-mounted as read-only (possible use cases for now only include them getting data from people, not them copying anything to the drive).

I have so far found that gnome-volume-manager is responsible for the handy auto-mount, but I didn't find any way to set options, like always mounting drives read-only.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

At this point I'll assume your system uses Udev and not HAL. So you want to create a rule file in */etc/udev/rules.d/* named, as an example, **25-usb-read-only.rules**

In that file put this:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", MODE="0555"
```

Restart udev or reboot and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

hal controls the options used when volumes are automounted.

Comment: This lets me dig a little deeper, but I've still not found a way to specify that all usb devices should be mounted read-only. :-/

Comment: Check `linux.sysfs_path` for presence of `/usb*/` and `/block/`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a read-only solution as well and found this post.  I also found a Lock License drive on the web (nexcopy).  It lets you copy to the USB stick, then run a command and turn it into a read-only USB drive.  It worked because the locking was done at the controller level so even a reg edit wouldn't change the status of the drive being read-only.